# Adding the numbers in table row using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add the numbers in the table cell without getting `NaN`.

```
<table id="sample" border="1">
<tr>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>2</td>
 <td>1</td>
 <td></td>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tobaxbb3/):

How it is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `isNaN()` function like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var colTotal=0;
 var col=$("#sample tr td");
    $(col).each(function()
        {
                colData=$(this).text();
                colTotal+=isNaN(parseInt(colData)) ? 0: parseInt(colData);
        });
    $('#sample tr:last td').text(isNaN(colTotal) ? 0: colTotal);

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tobaxbb3/4/)

Comment: I need also the total of numbers.

Comment: @jackrose see demo .

Answer (score 4):

Check this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    var colTotal=0;
    var col=$("#sample tr td");
    
    col.each(function() {
        colData=parseInt($(this).text(), 10);

        if (colData) {
            colTotal+=parseInt(colData);
        }
    });
    
    $('#sample tr:last td').text(colTotal);
         
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="sample" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

use `$.isNumeric(colData)`
[updated your link](http://jsfiddle.net/tobaxbb3/2/)

Comment: A few words of explanation would make this example even better.

Answer (score 3):

Just skip the blank values

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var colTotal=0;
    $("#sample td").each(function()
        {
            if ($(this).text())
                colTotal+=parseInt($(this).text());
        });
    $('#sample tr:last td').text(colTotal);                             
});
```

Comment: Check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tobaxbb3/5/